# How do you combine two like arrays of objects into a single array object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, next.js

I'm sorry if I'm asking a question that has been asked before, I had a hard time wording this one.

Basically, my API is returning an array of objects that are alike

```
const response.survey = [
  {
    1: { id: 1, user: user_1, points: 5 },
    2: { id: 2, user: user_2, points: 3 }...
  }
],
[
  {
    1: { id: 1, user: user_1, points: 10 },
    2: { id: 2, user: user_2, points: 0 }...
  }
],...
```

This can carry on for hundreds of arrays potentially, depending on users submissions through our forms. I'm stuck on how to combine them into something like:

```
[
  { user: user_1, points: 15 },
  { user: user_2, points: 3 },...
]
```

Note that the data that returned from the api has a key for the object, like Array[Object[1]], Array[Object[2]], etc.

In my current development environment, I'm returning 2x sets of 25 data points, so I would expect my final array of objects to be indexed at 25, but right now I'm getting 52. I believe there is a shorter way to handle this, but I cant quite figure it out and I keep going in circles.

Here is what I've tried:

```
let newArr = [];
response.survey.map((ballot, i) => {
    for (const key in ballot) {
        if (newArr.length == 0) {
            let newObj = {
                name: pos[key].user,
                points: pos[key].points
            }
            newArr.push(newObj);
        } else {
            for (let k = 0; k < newArr.length; k++) {
                if (newArr[k].name === pos[key].name) {
                    newArr[k].points += pos[key].points;
                } else {
                    if (k + 1 == newArr.length) {
                        let newObj = {
                            name: pos[key].name,
                            points: pos[key].points
                        }
                        newArr.push(newObj);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I've been working on this issue for so long that I've started to go into circles and heading down the wrong path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your example uses `response`, but your code doesn't use that variable. Similarly, what is `data.survey`? Please edit your question to make this a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you further.

Comment: that response doesn't look right. I get an error when trying to use it

Comment: Should be fixed now, sorry, I copied part of the code and just added an example of what the data looks like, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Yeah I'm just gonna go ahead and stop this train right here. I can't explain it any differently. Don't bother, I'll figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
 await fetch('/api/getBallots')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(async (data) => {
                let newArray = []

                data.ballots.map((ballot, i) => {
                    for (const key in ballot) {
                        if(!ballot[key].name) {
                            return;
                        } else {
                            let newObj = {
                                name: ballot[key].name,
                                points: ballot[key].points
                            }
                            newArray.push(newObj);
                        }
                        
                    }
                });
                let rankings = []; 
                for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
                    if (rankings.length == 0) {
                        rankings.push({
                            name: newArray[i].name,
                            points: newArray[i].points
                        });
                    } else {
                        const index = rankings.findIndex((item) => item.name == newArray[i].name);
                        if (index == -1) {
                            rankings.push({
                                name: newArray[i].name,
                                points: newArray[i].points
                            })
                        } else {
                            rankings[index].points += newArray[i].points;
                        }
                    }
                }          
        })
```